# Rails - Destroy children for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm banging my head trying to figure this one out.  I have the following form, which works *great*!

```
  <%= bootstrap_form_for @template do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :prompt, :class => :span6, :placeholder => "Which one is running?", :autocomplete => :off %>
     <%= f.select 'group_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@groups, 'id', 'name') %>
     <% 4.times do |num| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :template_assignments do |builder| %>
            <%= builder.hidden_field :choice_id %>
            <%= builder.check_box :correct %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

Then I have my model:

```
  class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :group
   has_many :template_assignments
   has_many :choices, :through => :template_assignments
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :template_assignments, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:choice_id].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
  end
```

When the form is submitted, the nested attributes are added *beautifully*.  However, when I want to delete a Template, I also want it to delete all the children "template_assignments" as well, which is what I assumed "allow_destroy => true"

So, I am trying this from the Rails Console (which could be my issue??)  I'll do something like:

```
 >> t = Template.find(1)
 #Which then finds the correct template, and I can even type: 
 >> t.template_assignments
 #Which then displays the nested attributes no problem, but then I try: 
 >> t.destroy
 #And it only destroys the main parent, and none of those nested columns in the TemplateAssignment Model.
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?  Is it because you can't do it in the Rails Console?  Do I need to do it in a form instead?  If so, how do I achieve this in a form?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify that child `template_assignments` should be destroyed upon the destruction of the parent `Template`:

```
# app/models/template.rb
has_many :template_assignments, dependent: :destroy
```

The following depicts the steps that Rails takes to destroy an object's dependent associations:

```
# from the Rails console
>>  t = Template.find(1)
#=> #<Template id:1>
>>  t.template_assignments.first
#=> #<TemplateAssignment id:1>
>>  t.destroy
#=> SELECT "template_assignments".* FROM "template_assignments" WHERE "template_assignments"."template_id" = 1
#=> DELETE FROM "template_assignments" WHERE "template_assignments"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
>>  TemplateAssignment.find(1)
#=> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find TemplateAssignment with id=1
```

The `:dependent` option can be specified on either side of the association, so it can *alternatively* be declared on the child association, rather than the parent:

```
# app/models/template_assignment.rb
belongs_to :template, dependent: :destroy
```

From the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

> has_many, has_one and belongs_to associations support the :dependent option. This allows you to specify that associated records should be deleted when the owner is deleted

Comment: to add to the above answer, the allow_destroy: true allows you to delete children on update, so for example you wanted to update the parent with some new children and also delete some. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#removing-objects